# Use UART Tx as digital output?

Tags: usb, serial, uart

Would it be possible to send a 5  V "true" signal from the Tx of a UART dongle?  As if it were a digital output?

[Here is](http://www.ebay.com/itm/170844489942?ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWNX%3aIT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649#ht_4007wt_1122) the UART adapter I purchased.

Comment: they did not think you were crazy, they were training to explain those are not intended to drive any real power, the power line is meant for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Would it be possible to send a 5 volt "true" signal form the Tx of a UART dongle? As if it were a digital output?

Conditional yes.

(1) The module you linked to has TTL output levels.
Assume it uses +5V = high and 0V = low (I see it has 3V3 and 5V mentioned on its PCB).

This means that RXD will be at 5V in the idle state, a start bit will be 0V, data bits will be +5 for logic 1 and 0V for logic 0 and sytop bits will be 5V.

When data is not being sent V_RXD will be 5V.

If you send a $00 signal (00000000 binary) the UART will output
 start + 8xdata + stop = 0 00000000 1
 The average DC level for this signal will be 1/10 x 5V = 0.5V.

If you resend successive $00 bytes at maximum channel speed the output may be as low as 0.5V DC when suitably filtered. Depending on hardware and the USB interface and PC configuration and the phase of the moon you MAY get interuptions between btes and see occasional 5V signal level.

If you add a very simple RC + diode filter such that a  RDX low discharges the cap immediately but charge up is via the resistor you can get low output during periods that the TXD line is high for limited periods.
 If $00 bytes are able to be sent end-to-end with no breaks an RC+D filter can have a time constant of only a bit time or so. If longer highs occur you need a longer time constant.

Whether an RC+D filter suits your needs depends on the data rate you want and system behaviour. If this is to control something that needs slow response - say  1 second or longer between changes and slow low to high change is acceptable, then this could work well for you.

---

**(2) External UART:**

**A better method** is to add an external  UART at the receiving end and decode the serial  signal to a parallel word. This gives you 8 bits of on off.

---

(3) If you want something already built that does what you want buy a **USB to parallel port (printer port) converter** - this gives 8 (or more) lines of on/off control from USB. Many on ebay. [Here is one for $US2.66 buy now withe free shipping](http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-To-DB25-25-pin-Female-Port-IEEE-1284-Parallel-Printer-Connect-Adapter-Cable-/290696923180?pt=US_Parallel_Serial_PS_2_Cables_Adapters&hash=item43aee3082c) !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! . Many more similar. Some people have commented that this may have printer functionality but not parallel port functionality. If so it should still be usable. At worst you may need to latch the data at "print time".

[image]

---

Added:

Indented text added as a result of a comment by CS:

- You specifically mentioned using the TX line, which is what I initially responded to.
  Others have mentioned using flow control lines (which did not visibly appear to be available on your device and were not mentioned in the ad)and some suggested buying a converter which had these signals.

  I recently spotted a USB-TTL serial converter on a local auction site and noted that the holes along the sides of the board had flow control labels. As your unit has similar holes it MAY also have similar functionality. So ...

Look at the bottom of your USB to TTL converter - it may have RTS/CTS and perhaps other signals available. If so, one or more of these can be controlled as an output.

See photo below. This is your unit. Note holes marked by red lines.

[image]

The photo below is a unit sold on a local auction site.
 Of the 4 lines marked by arrows, 2 will be outputs and two will be inputs. These are controllable as part of a COM port. Yours may have these lines active or they may be disabled. Do you have a data sheet or detailed model number?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that USB to parallel printer cables can be used to bitbang? I'm pretty sure that for something like that a real PCI/PCI-E card is actually needed because almost always USB to parallel port devices create a virtual printer and aren't bitbangable.

Comment: @TobyJaffey - I was not the user of "crazy". You may have +1'd the wrong person :-).

Comment: Nope, I think sending 0x00 and using a filter is nuts, but I like it.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - If it does not give you port access but does give printer access then presumably it would strobe a latch (which could be powered from the port) and you could make a logic arrangement with a few transistors or gates that allowed bit set/clear with minimal hardware. / For the serial port A microcontroller acting as a uART and serial to latched parallel converter sounds like a simple solution.

Comment: This answer seems over-rated as it missed out on the obvious and generally (in the usual cases where supported) superior use of the flow control signals as steady outputs.  Editing that idea as an afterthought into the answer after others had posted it doesn't seem quite fair to those raised it from the start.

Comment: @Chris - Whatever. I (with a very few notable exceptions :-) ) do not answer for ratings, I answer to try to be useful to the maximum number of people possible, and copycat post priori answers to my posts are common. I've been aware of flow control signals for 40+ years and was aware that others mentioned getting a dongle that included them. The user made no mention of them on his device AND they were not on his picture AND not mentioned in the ad. I added the extra because I saw the device shown on a local auction site and saw that the die holes were for flow control signals and that ...

Comment: @ChrisStratton ... his had the same style of holes so quite possibly these may also be for RTS CTS etc. ||Note that I explicitly addressed his actual question and that there is a gap between "use flow control" and what the user knows about or "buy one with ..." and what the user has. || So I took the effort to add the extra as I thought it would be of possible use. If all that rates an overrated, so be it.
| Typo above: "die holes" -> "side holes".

Comment: @ChrisStratton - text added addressing your comments.

Comment: Wow - the phantom downvoter strikes 5.4 ish years on. (December 2017). Whoever you are - please contact me and I'll explain the meaning of the word "useful". And anything else that you do not understand about this subject, if you wish.

Answer (score 4):

I did not think you crazy for asking, even though the answer was clearly 'impossible'.

On your new question: yes, you can probably control the level of the Tx pin, by either sending nothing at all, or setting the 'break' condition. (but the break condition is not very well sepecified, it might be that some OSes or drivers interpret it as having a limited time. IME Windows and Linux do NOT fall in this category.)

But it is probably far easier to set the levels of the various control pins. How this is done depends on your programming language and library.

When you use a standard serial port or an off-the-shelve usb-to-serial converter you het outputs at RS232 polarity (=inverted) and level (-10V / +10V or something like that).

It is probably easier to use a 'bare' converter chip, without the RS232 level shifter. FTDIchip makes some, check http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBTTLSerial.htm

IME usb-to-parallel converters are useless for your purpose, because they create a virtual *printer* port, not a virtual *parallel* port.

Comment: +1 I don't know what IME means, but I know it's easy to set an infinite or any length break in Windows.

Comment: @kenny - IME = "In My Experience"

Comment: I'm not sure which language to use yet.  I am thinking I will use Python or C# because (from the googleing that I have done) it seems like Python has a very good "PySerial" library, and (from experience) C# has .NET backing it which is also very easy to use.  But if people have other languages or libraries they recommend I am happy to hear suggestions.

Comment: I use Python and pyserial, to my satisfaction.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can keep the TX pin high or low at all times. Every byte you send will have a start bit (logic low) and a stop bit (logic high). Your best bet would be to get a usb-to-uart adaptor that has DTR and/or RTS pins. These lines can be toggled easily.

**However.**

This answer is only as good as your question, which is not that good really, as you don't give many details. If you tell us what exactly is that you're trying to do, what hardware you have (and so on), we might be able to give you a better advice.

My first question would be this:
If you have an arduino and a relay module for it, why do you have to use some roundabout way to solve your problem?

Comment: +1 for suggesting DTR pin instead of TX.

Answer (score 3):

The CP2102 supports DTR and RTS flow control signals. These can be used as USB controlled outputs.

From the looks of the ebay picture you posted, the pins are routed to J2 or J3.

Comment: Yes.  And if you can find a board populated with the CP2103, that has some GPIOs as well.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually possible to use tx pin as digital:  If nothing is transmitted the output is high level. And if you use break option for serial port in any programming language you put tx pin in low state.

Comment: Two things do need to be kept in mind.  The output level may change unexpectedly if some driver or other operating system component resets the USART system.  Sending of data will generate a pulsed output determined by the bitrate, framing and data content.  The available power is limited to what the IO provider though to offer as a digital logic level output but 2-10 mA is often available if you are happy with poor voltage regulation.

Answer (score 0):

Typing 'ctrl spacebar' in a com port terminal seems to send a nice active low pulse on the TX line of my TTL converter.